# Route management issue Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

This is part of my routes/web.php file

```
if(Request::is('users/*'))
    {
        require __DIR__.'/users.php';
    }
```

I have a file named users.php under the same folder

```
Route::get('profile',[
    'middleware' => 'auth',
    'uses' =>'home\HomeController@profile'])->name('userprofile');
```

I'm trying to access users/profile route. But it is not working. Please help

Thanks in Advance

Comment: The best way is to create route prefix and set all route you need under that! This simply way to manange any module routes and common prefix URL!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Route::prefix('users')->group(function() {
    Route::get('profile', 'home\HomeController@profile')
         ->middleware('auth')->name('userprofile');
});
```